# What is the differential equation connecting $P$ and $t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Compressed air is escaping from a container. The pressure of the air in the container at time $t$ is $P$ and the constant atmospheric pressure of the air outside the container is $A$. The rate of decrease of $P$ is proportional to the square root of the pressure difference $(P-A)$.

The derived differential equation for this system is $$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}t} = -k\sqrt{P-A}$$

I know that $P$ is dependent on $t$, and as such, $P$ is a function of $t$. Then, $$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}t} = -k\sqrt{P(t)-A}$$

Is this the differential equation connecting $P$ and $t$, and would it be possible to solve for the general solution without actually knowing what $P(t)$ is?

Thanks.

Comment: @KamalSaleh It is separable.

Answer (score 0):

Your differential equation is correct, assuming your first paragraph is correct. The equation is separable. Rearranging, we have $$\frac{\mathrm dP}{\sqrt{P - A}} = -k\mathrm dt.$$

Integrating from $t = 0$ to $t = t'$ and replacing $t'$ with $t$, we obtain $$2\sqrt{P(t) - A} - 2\sqrt{P(0) - A} = -kt.$$

Now, you can solve for $P(t)$.

Comment: If $P$ is a function of $t$, shouldn't we be integrating $P(t)$ w.r.t. $t$?

Comment: @Abdulrahman No. We have $\mathrm{d}P$ on the left hand side (LHS) and $\mathrm{d}t$ on the right hand side (RHS), so we integrate the LHS w.r.t. $P$ and the RHS w.r.t. $t$. I would suggest you read/watch a video about separation of variables.

Comment: Alright thanks.